# Error java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: android

Tengo un error que me salta al querer mostrar el `infowindow` personalizado de google maps, el método `showInfoWindow` es el que hace saltar el error.

Dentro de la clase `InfoWindowMarer` al hacer debug note que esta llamando demasiadas veces a los métodos sobrescritos `getInfoContents` y `getInfoWindow` de la clase `InfoWindowAdapter`, en otra vista estoy utilizando la misma para mostrar y sale correctamente, cuando hago la llamda a un servicio rest, en la implementacion de la respuesta implemento el siguiente codigo:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowMarker(getApplicationContext(), markerDesde, viaje.getPasajero()));
                    animateCameraToPoint(viaje.getPuntoDesde());
                    markerDesde.showInfoWindow();
                }
            });
```

En el método onMapReady con la variable `markerDesde` se hace lo siguiente:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptionsDesde = new MarkerOptions().position(viaje.getPuntoDesde()).title(getString(R.string.desde));
    //markerOptionsDesde.draggable(true);
    markerOptionsDesde.flat(true)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
    markerDesde = map.addMarker(markerOptionsDesde);
markerHasta = map.addMarker(markerOptionsHasta);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(midPoint(markerDesde.getPosition().latitude, markerDesde.getPosition().longitude, markerHasta.getPosition().latitude, markerHasta.getPosition().longitude))
            .zoom(14) // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(angleBteweenCoordinate(markerDesde.getPosition().latitude, markerDesde.getPosition().longitude, markerHasta.getPosition().latitude, markerHasta.getPosition().longitude)) // Sets the orientation of the camera to
            .tilt(30) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Luego en este método también se realiza una consulta a la api directions para trazar una polilinea entre 2 puntos.

onMapReady se llama cuando se inicia el Activity, el problema se da cuando presiono un botón que consulta a un servicio rest, en la respuesta intento mostrar el marcador y ahi explota.

Stacktrace:

```
11-03 22:05:56.991 14532-14532/com.system.sumo.retaxi E/UncaughtException: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
at android.os.Parcel.obtain(Parcel.java:314)
at vw.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:88)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.c.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.d.c(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.S.g(Unknown Source)
at abw.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:145)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzf$zza$zza.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.ImageRefresherMarker.onSuccess(ImageRefresherMarker.java:17)
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:657)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.InfoWindowMarker.getInfoContents(InfoWindowMarker.java:42)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzd$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at vw.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:112)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.c.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.d.c(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.S.g(Unknown Source)
at abw.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:145)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzf$zza$zza.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.ImageRefresherMarker.onSuccess(ImageRefresherMarker.java:17)
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:657)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.InfoWindowMarker.getInfoContents(InfoWindowMarker.java:42)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzd$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at vw.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:112)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.c.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.d.c(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.S.g(Unknown Source)
at abw.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:145)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzf$zza$zza.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.ImageRefresherMarker.onSuccess(ImageRefresherMarker.java:17)
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:657)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.InfoWindowMarker.getInfoContents(InfoWindowMarker.java:42)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzd$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at vw.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:112)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.c.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.d.c(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.S.g(Unknown Source)
at abw.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:145)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzf$zza$zza.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.ImageRefresherMarker.onSuccess(ImageRefresherMarker.java:17)
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:657)
at com.system.sumo.retaxi.utils.maps.InfoWindowMarker.getInfoContents(InfoWindowMarker.java:42)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzd$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at vw.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:112)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.G.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.c.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.d.c(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando te encuentras un error: `java.lang.StackOverflowError` significa que tienes un problema con llamadas recursivas de los métodos. Verifica cada una de las llamadas dentro de tu código.